# How to sanitize ruby-pg data before select?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, sanitize

I have the following db interogation in ruby-pg:

`a = product[:id].in(Spree::Product.joins(:taxons).where("spree_products_taxons.taxon_id in (params)").map(&:id))`

How do I sanitize the `params` data, so I can sefely pass it to this particular query ? It's passed on as an array and for the database should be a list of integers 2,3,4

Comment: try with `.where("spree_products_taxons.taxon_id in (?)", params).map(&:id))`